# var in textarea from sql?

Tags: php, html, textarea

I tried to make a form with textarea content taken from sql and it's working well except for 1 thing i want to make...

i have some text in the sql like "hi $name, welcome" (for example)
and when i echo it in the textarea i get the same "hi $name, welcome"
but i want the $name to change for what i want...

```
<?php
    $supplier = "David";
    $branch = "name";
    $msg = $row['msg'];
?>
      <textarea rows="7" name="msg" cols="50" style="font-size: 11"><?php echo $msg; ?></textarea>
```

EDIT:
that's what i get:
[image]

and that's the sql:
[image]

how i can change it?

thanks!

Comment: You could use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the text $name in the message with the value in the $name variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store a message in the database and replace some words on output, don't save it as PHP code. Create a template with placeholders for the variable data instead, something like:

```
Hi, {supplier}. Lorem ipsum {branch}
```

and then just replace those using [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$msg = str_replace(['{supplier}', '{branch}'], [$supplier, $branch], $msg);
```

Answer (score -1):

your syntax is wrong. write like this:

```
<?php
$name="David";
$msg=$row['msg'];
?>
<textarea rows="7" name="msg" cols="50" style="font-size: 11"><?php echo $msg ?></textarea>
```

you have to open php tag and then close it before write html in php tag like what i write.

Comment: ofcourse i did it, that's not the problem... it's printing to me only the $msg taken from the sql and ignoring the $name in the msg itself...

Comment: that's what i get: https://i.imgur.com/R0UdoyH.jpg i tried ".$var." and {$var} but as you can see... nothing and the sql table: https://i.imgur.com/MWyHxJS.jpg

Comment: @SaarAsor - What are those images suppose to show us? The only thing those have in common with your question is the word "hi". They just made things unclear.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this is one field in the database  :-B

Comment: If you want do do "template like"  entries in your database YOU SHOULD DECIDE WHICH FORMAT YOU USE.  Not  ".$foo."  for one variable and  {$bar} for the other.  

Also you need  to understand that database contents are usually excaped so there will be no replacemet  of the variables.    so it just prints out the $foo  and $bar without replacing the variables.

Comment: sorry if i wasnt claer, that was fr the example... str_replace() is what i was looking for. tnx everyone!